# Efficient NoSQL user design

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, nosql

I am using MongoDB with Node for a relatively simple web application that involves users signing up and authenticating their login information. I have experience with relational DB's, but am fairly new to the NoSQL game. I am wondering if I am efficiently using the NoSQL database with the current format of my data storage?

My code as of now to save a user looks like so:

```
db.users.save({email: req.body.email, display_name: req.body.displayName, password: req.body.password}, function(err, saved) {
    if( err || !saved ) 
        console.log("User not saved");
    else 
        console.log("User saved in MongoDB");
});
```

What is happening here is that each user is being generated his or her own document in a MongoDB "collection." I am wondering if this is going to slow things down when the user base becomes relatively large, and I need to quickly find users for authentication?

Any answer that can help me out conceptually or point me in a direction to learn more would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB, what's right and what's wrong depends mostly on how you are going to interact with your data. But one document per user seems like a viable strategy for most use-cases.

To speed up retrieval of users, remember to [add indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/) for those fields you want to retrieve them by.

In this case, the document you save has no `_id` field. That means a new document will be generated with a newly generated _id, even when there is already an entry with the same values in the database. Is this what you want? When you want to use the `.save(doc)` function for updating an existing document, you need to have the _id of the document with the same value as the one you want to update.

Comment: That was very helpful @Philipp, thank you. I was not aware of the ability to add indexes in MongoDB. As far as your question, that is definitely not what I want. I was hoping if you attempted to sign up a user with an email that already exists in the database, I would be able to catch that immediately. Is my best bet then to attempt to `find()` the email in the DB first before I proceed to save?

Comment: @JackRyan It would be better to create an [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on the email field and wait for an error. When you `find `first, you might still get duplicates when two identical users are created in the same millisecond, which can happen in a large-scale web application.